# Setting up angular CLI but getting no NPM error message

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to set up Angular CLI on my first angular project but keep getting the same errors that when I use the command
`npm install -g @angular/cli` in the terminal of my project like youtube tutorial says
It keeps telling me that

```
Program 'npm' failed to run: No application is associated with the specified file for this operationAt line:1 char:1
+ npm
+ ~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ npm
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

I did install node JS on my system and I made sure that the environment variable path is set up with npm and node.
So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which OS do you use? What does `npm --version` return? Did you restart your terminal after you installed nodejs?

Comment: I'm running windows and any npm command I run gives the same error.I did restart my computer

Comment: It looks like something with the installation went wrong. Maybe you should uninstall and reinstall node.js. [Here](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-node-js-npm-on-windows) is some documentation. Does `node -v` returns an error as well?